# Mysql- How can I find the memory usage of indexes

Tags: mysql, optimization

mysqltuner tells me to increase key_buffer_size dramatically. I dont have free memory to do it therefore I prefer to remove unnecessary indexes if any.

How can I find the memory usage of indexes? (how large a memory each index occupy)?

Is there a reporting tool or queries which can get this information ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [SHOW TABLE STATUS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-table-status.html) ..?